# remove String row in pandas data frame when number of words is less than N

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am pre-processing dataset for NLP classification task, i want to drop the sentences with less than 3 words, the code i tried drop the words with less than 3 letters:

```
import re
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
# remove words between 1 and 3
shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,3}\b')
print(shortword.sub('', text))
```

how to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas
text = {"header":["The quick fox","The quick fox brown jumps hight","The quick"]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(text)
df = df[df['header'].str.split().str.len().gt(2)]  
print(df)
```

The above snippet filters the dataframe of 'header' column length greater than 2 words.

For more on pandas dataframe, refer https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hope** this helps you.

```
import re
text= "Hi, Yaman Afadar. Welcome to stackoverflow website. You are pre-processing dataset for NLP classification task. you want to drop the sentences with less than 3 words. Here a sample code. Coud you try it please! The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. So, Hello everyone."

sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', text)

print (sentences)

output='\n'.join(s for s in sentences if len(s.split())>3 )

print (output)
```

**[Output]:**

```
['Hi, Yaman Afadar', 'Welcome to stackoverflow website', 'You are pre-processing dataset for NLP classification task', 'you want to drop the sentences with less than 3 words', 'Here a sample code', 'Coud you try it please', 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'So, Hello everyone', '']
```

**Sentences with more than 3 words**

> ```
> Welcome to stackoverflow website
> You are pre-processing dataset for NLP classification task
> you want to drop the sentences with less than 3 words
> Here a sample code
> Coud you try it please
> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much!!